# Calendar in single line

Tags: shell-script, date

I am trying to manipulate `cal` command to give me output in a single line with date and just below the day of the week so I can use it in excel for a script or html. Like below.

```
Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Comment: The post didn't show the correct output, the way i wanted is date and just below it the day of the week.

Comment: so output would be in two lines?

Comment: yes, sort of, but the alignment should also be proper so it can be exported to csv,excel or html, because these will not be only lines in the sheet.

Comment: Let me give some brief,

it will be like some columns at the beginning with some title and then adjacent to the date and below it day column title and from there the format i wanted, as there will be entries in the initial columns, this date,day is the tracker which will have entries from my script. make sense?

Comment: @Sid Please update the question rather than giving details in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash` (or `ksh93`), and GNU `date`:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 8; ++i )); do
    printf '%s\t' "$( date -d "now +$i days" +"%a" )"
done

echo

for (( i = 0; i < 8; ++i )); do
    printf ' %d\t' "$( date -d "now +$i days" +"%e" )"
done

echo
```

The `%a` format will give you the abbreviated day of the week in the current locale, while `%e` gives you the day of the month as an integer.

Result (tab-separated):

```
Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri     Sat     Sun     Mon     Tue
 7       8       9      10      11      12      13      14
```

**UPDATE for `ksh93` after comments:** (note, this doesn't work since the shell doesn't seem to verify the dates properly)

```
#!/bin/ksh93

yearmonth=$( date +"%Y%m" )

d=1
while printf '%(%a)T\t' "$( printf '%s%02d' "$yearmonth" "$d" )" 2>/dev/null
do
    (( ++d ))
done
echo

days_this_month=$(( --d ))
while (( d > 0 )); do
    printf ' %d\t' "$(( days_this_month - (--d) ))"
done
echo
```

`yearmonth` is first set to the current year and month on the `YYYYMM` format. I then loop over all weekdays of this month. The loop sets `wday` to the abbreviated weekday, and it will terminate when I try to get the weekday of a date that is invalid.

The second loop just prints integers, as many as we need to fill out the month.

Output for February 2017:

```
Wed     Thu     Fri     Sat     Sun     Mon     Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri     Sat     Sun     Mon     Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri     Sat     Sun     Mon     Tue     Wed     Thu     Fri     Sat     Sun     Mon     Tue
 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24      25      26      27      28
```

**Solution using `ksh93` with Perl and Date::Calc**:

```
#!/bin/ksh93

ym=( $(date +"%Y %m") )

days=$( perl -MDate::Calc -e 'print Date::Calc::Days_in_Month($ARGV[0],$ARGV[1])' -- "${ym[0]}" "${ym[1]}" )

for d in {1..$days}; do
    printf '%(%a)T\t' "$( printf '%d-%d-%02d' "${ym[@]}" "$d" )"
done
echo

for d in {1..$days}; do
    printf '%d\t' "$d"
done
echo
```

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, Would it work month wise? as in the for loop should take maximum limit as the month's last day (30/31/28). Moreover it will display from current date, what if i want from 1st day of every month irrespective of what day i choose to run the script? Because this way I will have to make sure to run it on first day of the month which i can achieve from crontab.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't usually mention `zsh` in my answers as it's a shell I don't use on a daily basis. Yes, it could easily be converted to plain `sh`, but the syntax is not as neat. Thanks for pointing me to the `%(...)T` format -- useful.

Comment: @Sid It was not clear from the question what you wanted. I may update my answer in a short while.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was trying the stress that `for((;;))` was in ksh88  as well which was wrong, as that was added in ksh93. I keep getting that one wrong.  Comment removed.

Comment: @Sid Update my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it isn't working, for testing i saved the code in a script file and ran it, but it didn't give any output. would any of the module require anything on AIX, it does have bash.

Comment: @Sid It does require GNU `date`. This is available on some systems as `gdate`. What shell are you using? Do you have `ksh93`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I did check for the ksh version, I do have ksh93, i went into that shell and tried again but still no output, it ran fine in linux though. Am I doing something wrong on AIX, it's default shell is bash, should I mention the shell ksh93 at the beginning of the script?

Comment: @Sid I have updated it specifically for `ksh93` now.

Comment: Yes it worked, you just removed a variable in while loop, rest it was same, so does while loop doesn't work incremental variable conditions or something? And I might need further help for the parent script as this just a module of it. Do you have any suggestion on How can I shift this output to right in order to have other columns. For e.g

                                   Day        1     2    3    4    5                       
                                  Date     Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun 
Title 1  Title 2 Title 3  Title 4

Comment: @Kusalananda, I know it's an edited request, otherwise you have answered my initial question, in case you want me to write another post I can do that.

Comment: @Sid The script failed to run properly for you because you don't have GNU `date`. With `ksh93` it's easy to format date strings without GNU `date`. The variable I removed was just a tiny optimization (it wasn't needed). To print further columns, you already have `$days_this_month` (28 this month), so you would be able to use that for looping: `for ((d=1;d<days_this_month;++d)); do printf 'Title %d\t' "$d"; done; echo`.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, I was just working further and I just checked that February month date is coming out as 31 not 28. I am trying to figure out the logic of your code to sort this out

Comment: @Sid I've seen your comment and I'm letting a solution to this brew while I'm thinking of other things. Could you let me know what Unix you're on, please?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am using Linux & AIX, Did you check the code I posted, I used your code only.

Comment: @Sid If you are able to use GNU `date` on the AIX system (it's part of GNU coreutils`) then that would be the easiest solution. I will add a Perl solution too, and if that doesn't help, please accept one of the other answers.

Comment: @Kusalananda, perl script gave me errors

Can't Locate Date/Calc.pm

Also I am focusing on your simple suggestion of day_this_month variable and I used it in first while loop of your script and used a simple for loop to display dates. It works, is there any issue?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` alone (only builtins):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime
now=$EPOCHSECONDS
strftime -s year %Y $now
strftime -s month %m $now
strftime -rs s %Y,%m,%d,%H $year,$month,1,12
output=()
while
  for field (a d m) strftime -s $field %-$field $s
  ((month == m))
do
  output+=($a $((d)))
  ((s += 86400))
done
print -C $(($#output / 2)) $output
```

With `bash` (4.2 or above) alone (only builtins), but assuming the week day abbreviations are 3 characters or less and are all made of single-byte characters only in your locale (so won't work properly in many locales beside English ones).

```
#! /bin/bash -
printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1

printf -v d '%(%-d)T' "$now"
printf -v h '%(%-H)T' "$now"
printf -v month '%(%-m)T' "$now"

s=$((now +(12-h)*3600 - (d-1) * 86400))

l1= l2=

while
  for field in a d m; do printf -v "$field" "%(%-$field)T" "$s"; done
  ((month == m))
do
  printf -v l1 '%s%-3s ' "$l1" "$a"
  printf -v l2 '%s%-3s ' "$l2" "$d"
  ((s += 86400))
done
printf '%s\n' "$l1" "$l2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just extract the corresponding lines directly from the *cal* output, as follows:

```bash
>cal|sed -n '2p;/_/p'
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

(but note, that *cal* will use the two-letter weekday abbreviations, at least on my system)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cal | perl -0ne '
   if(/(.*)(Su.*?)\n(\h*)( 1.*?)\s*$/s){
      $s= length($3); 
      $b=$2 x 5; 
      $n= $4 =~ s/[^\d ]//gr; 
      print substr($b,$s,length($n)),"\n$n\n" }'

We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu
 1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15 16 17 18  19 20 21 22 23 24 25  26 27 28
```

Explanation: the output of cal is divided by the regular expression `(.*)(Su.*?)\n(\h*)( 1.*?)`

```
 Febr 2017  \nSu Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  \n          1 2 3 4 \n 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
($1         )($2                   )  ($3     )($4                         ... )
```

- `$2` is used to build the bar of the weeks (`$b = $2 x 5`)
- `$4` is used to build the list of the days, after removing `\n` and highlighting characters (`$n= $4 =~ s/[^\d ]//gr`)
- the length of `$3` is used to remove the last month' days out of the bar of the weeks (`substr($b,$s,length($n))`)

Comment: I like this approach. Could you please fix the "SaSu" issue that stick together and mark the current date? That would be awesome.